# How to trigger a HREF tag from JavaScript in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have dynamically created a href in js file.

I have to trigger the `<a href>` from the js file and the link is not present in the HTML part. But unable to trigger the link.

```
let content = <a href='www.google.com'></a>;
```

I have to trigger the above statement from js.

**NB: I can't use jquery**

Comment: Without more context, we won't be able to help you. Can you please include all the relevant template and JavaScript code? You can [edit] your question to include more code. What you're trying to do is generally possible in LWC, but we don't have enough information to help right now.

Comment: I formed a `<a href='www.google.com'></a>`  tag in js file (`let content = <a href='www.google.com'></a>`); but I can't show it in html part.

How can I trigger the <a href> tag from js page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use innerHTML.

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  renderedCallback() {
    const content = '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>';
    this.template.querySelector('div').innerHTML = content;
  }
}
```

Or, if you mean to say you want to redirect to a website:

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
```

Or, if you want to trigger a download:

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'https://www.google.com';
document.body.appendChild(a); // Firefox apparently requires this
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Note that this demo won't work entirely right because of sandboxing, but you should see the effect demonstrated.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/oh8WZMLL5HvjSv2NKM8O/src/app.js?p=stories).